# rake file command, ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task, rakefile

So I have a hospital, and the hospital has clinics. I am trying to set up different hours within the clinics based off of weekends vs weekends.  I keep running into this error being that I have a wrong number of arguments, (2 for 1), and i'm not sure what do to to get around this.

```
  task set_clinic_hours: :environment do
    hospital = Customer.where(slug: "hospital").first
      hospital.clinics.each do |clinic|
        clinic.update_operating_hours(33_400, 74_800)
        clinic.operating_hours.where(day: [0, 6]).update_all(10_400,    75_400)
      end
    end
```

I don't know why i'm getting that error, and i'm also not able to get the rake task to work out properly. Would anybody be able/willing to take a stab at this for me?

Comment: On which line you get that error?

Comment: hospital.clinics.each do |clinic|

Comment: Pretty sure it'll be on the call to `update_all`, What are you actually trying to update?

Comment: and also clinic.update_operating_hours(33_400, 74_800)

Comment: oh yeah, i am getting an error with that part as well. however it is looking like it may be something with one of my gems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_all` is expecting one argument but you are giving it two. That argument should be a hash of the fields to change and the new values. I think you want something like:

```
clinic.operating_hours.where(day: [0, 6]).update_all(hours: [10_400, 75_400])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was struggling for almost 2 hours!